# Find the exact content in a website by using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a function that I could save and display the **exact place** I selected in a website.

And I've found out `getSelection()` object in javascript is something I am looking for (cause it save all the information). But now I'm trying to highlight the place where I've chose before by using the `getSelection()` object.

Could I back trace the place by using `getSelection()`? I think there should be some better solutions but I couldn't think of any right now.

In other words, I'm trying to save some data, for tracing back the exact place I selected.

Did anyone have any ideas? Or better solution. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to distribute this or is it just for personal use? If it's the latter, you could simply use right click and "inspect" or "element information" and you'll get the exact place you're currently on. In the first case it's more complicated as you have to find the element that is at least the parent of *all* elements with selected content.

Comment: In other words, I'm trying to save some data, for tracing back the exact place where I select.

Answer (score 1):

If you know what the parent tag is, you could loop through those, and use a regex to find where the copy is within that element.

Using something like the below, will wrap all instances of the matching phrase in a span with a yellow background.

I've put an example fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/TDcKX/2/

```
function find_phrase(phrase){
    var p_tags = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

    for (var i = 0; i < p_tags.length; i++){
        var p = p_tags[i], regex = new RegExp(phrase, 'g');
        p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML.replace(regex, '<span style="background-color:yellow;">' + phrase + '</span>');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, but I'm looking for some solutions that can help me find the exact place I selected. For example if there is two sentence that are the same, in a same paragraph.  I've selected one of them, how could I find out which sentence did I selected.

Comment: Ok, you should be able to do that by using createRange. Which requires the dom node, and the startOffset and endOffset of the selection. All of which you get from getSelection, as 'baseOffset' and 'extentOffset'. Once you've created a range you could pass that to getSelectedText(). A reference for creating a range is at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createRange and a reference for then using it is at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getSelection    - I can't create a fiddle right now, but will have a look if you have any difficulty with this